# jQuery doesn't work in Nokia E71 browser

Tags: jquery, nokiabrowser, e71

I'm unable to use jQuery 1.5.2 with Nokia E71 browser.

I found this problem reported in [jQuery bug tracker](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/6246) without future fix.

Is there any possible workaround?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think that it has to do with jQuery since, jQuery relies on browser being able to execute JavaScript. So if browser is unable to do that, then it is also unable to run jQuery web sites, and vice versa... but I'm just thinking that based on logic. Would like to know the answer... :D

Comment: @Cipi: please, refer to [that link](http://jquerymobile.com/gbs/). It shows that it has to do with jQuery (Mobile version in this case).

Comment: @Zakaria I'm using jQuery, not jQuery Mobile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use jQuery with Nokia E71 mobile browser I [changed jQuery code](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/parse-error-with-webkit-mobile-browsers-and-jquery-1-4-2).

Replace `div.attachEvent("onclick", function click() {`

with `div.attachEvent("onclick", function(){`

And

Replace `div.detachEvent("onclick", click);`

with `div.detachEvent("onclick", arguments.callee);`

Comment: The pages renders but I'm unable to do an AJAX request. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891331/jquery-ajax-requests-not-working-in-nokia-e71-browser

Answer (score 0):

Nokia E71 is using the S60 third generation OS.
If you are using tje jQuery Mobile framework to build touch-friendly web applications/sites, then you have [this list](http://jquerymobile.com/gbs/) to take in consideration.

It tells that the third generation of that OS renders your pages in "very low quality" (if you use that framework of course).

Please, post us the code you are experimenting and jquery version you are using.
Regards.

Comment: I'm using jQuery, not jQuery Mobile.

Comment: jQuery mobile is based on jQuery (it's an official branch). Can you browse [this jquery test page](http://view.jquery.com/tags/1.3.2/test/) with your device?

Comment: Same problem reported [here](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/6246). "I receive almost no output. No useragent string, no test results, just the html loads as if there is no Javascript."

Comment: @Diogo: I visited your link and it seems that all the versions that come after the 1.3 one cannot run on the E71 browser.