# jQuery AJAX requests not working on Nokia E71 browser

Tags: jquery, timeout, nokiabrowser, e71

After fixing [jQuery compatibility with Nokia E71 browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5299636/jquery-doesnt-work-in-nokia-e71-browser) to render pages now I'm unable to do an AJAX request.

I've tried consuming a WS REST using JSONP with jQuery 1.5.2 but all the requests timed out.

Comment: Have you tried using a newer version of jQuery instead, say 1.5.2 or 1.6?

Answer (score 0):

Nokia E71 won't support `JQuery`. Please try with the latest `Nokia` models.